# A non American TV Show / Movie about immortal werewolves

Tags: story-identification, werewolf

It was a TV Show or a movie I am not completely sure. The names of characters and places sounded foreign like Latin America / Spain  (or maybe Italy or France).

The story was about immortal werewolves. Some of the characters worked for the police and tried to investigate some werewolf related murders.

A conversation with a friend reminded me that one of the characters was a judge.

Other characters were teenagers. One of them was a werewolf.

The murders were related to some ritual to kill a werewolf/stop the lycanthropy spread.

The werewolves were immortal - their wounds healed fast. One of them survived a direct shot to the chest.

There were at least two werewolves, possibly more. One of the werewolves might have been a teacher, the other one was a teenager.

One of the scenes I remember was that somebody tried to find the werewolves by bringing some kind of magic flower to the school dance (my memory suggests wolf's bane but I may be mistaken).

There was a big focus on romantic relationships between different people.

I watched this movie/series probably around three years ago but it might be older.

Comment: [Teen Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Wolf_(2011_TV_series))? (though it's an American series, so probably it's not what you are looking for)

Comment: According to wikipedia, there an [episode in the second season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Wolf_(season_2)#ep21) involving _wolfsbane_ and a _party_ that could match your recollections (I'm  reluctant to write this as an answer as I never followed the series, so I have no direct knowledge of it).

Comment: Sadly it's not it, it was definitely some Romance language series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be *[Luna, el misterio de Calenda](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2124494/)*? It's about a female judge named Sara Cruz who moves to the town of Calenda, where she discovers there's a werewolf population. One of the plotlines involved Sara's daughter, Leire, and her relationship with Joel, one of the local werewolves who suffers from a disease related to his lycanthropy.

I found it by searching for *spanish tv show werewolf detectives*, which brought up [List of Spanish television series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Spanish_television_series) on Wikipedia.